# access : populate textbox separately with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Acces I have a continuous form with independant textbox.
I try to fill it using vba for each record find in the query result, but this fill all the textbox with the same value.

[image: My form]
This is my Form

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim WO As String
WO = Forms![Maintenance input formulaire]![Maintenance input sous formulaire].Form![WONumber]

query = "select comment from SystemAircraftStatus where SystemID = " + CStr(Me.SystemID) + " and WO = '" + WO + "';"
Debug.Print (query)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query)

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Me.Texte54.Value = rs.Fields("comment") 'PROBLEME : est appliqué a tous les enregistrements
End If

End Sub
```

and this is the VBA code, only the first result (with "autre") have a comment.

Is there a solution to fill each textbox separately ?

Comment: Selon votre code, vous essayez de remplir Me.Text54 par le contenu de la colonne comments de votre recordset.

Comment: Do u need to fill the textbox using VBA if not DLookUp looks like a much simpler solution to your problem

Comment: I have try DLookUp but it is very slow, finaly it's done, i've insert it in my query with a field like (select ... from ...) as ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it fills all the textboxes with one value: It is a continous

form and the textbox is **unbound**.

The textbox has to be **bound** to a value in the recorset of the form in order to show different values.

I suggest you use the recordset object to bind the textbox to a value in the recordset of the form. Like this:

```
Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
dim qry as string

qry = _
"select WO, comment from SystemAircraftStatus where SystemID = " + CStr(Me.SystemID) + " and WO = '" + WO + "';"

me.recordset = qry

End Sub
```

You need to select the two values directly in your SQL query for the recordset object.

Then you use the properties of the textbox to bind it to the value in the query.

Best regards